# 'String is not recognised as valid date time'

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am using Bootstrap datetimepicker, I am taking field two fields in my viewmodels ('StartDate', and 'EndDate') which is of string type and in my entity which is of Datetime type. when I convert into format..it gives me exception like.

> String is not recognized as valid date time.

My View Model Class.

```
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RefNo{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? PaxNo { get; set; }

    [Required]

    public string StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]

    public string EndDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "StartCity")]
    public string StartCityId { get; set; }
```

My Entity Class

```
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public  string RefernceNo { get; set; }

    public int PaxNo { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public int StartCityId { get; set; }
```

Controller :- PostMethod

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddTour(TourViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    var loginUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
                    model.Cities = _cityRepository.GetCities();
                    model.Coaches = GetCoaches();

                    var startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(model.StartDate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));

                    var endDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(model.EndDate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
                    var tour = new Tour()
                    {
                        Name = model.Name,
                        RefernceNo = model.RefNo,
                        PaxNo = model.PaxNo ?? 0,
                        StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(model.StartDate.ToString()),
                        EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(model.EndDate.ToString()),
                        StartCityId = int.Parse(model.StartCityId),
                        EndCityId = int.Parse(model.EndCityId),
                        Opeartor = model.Operator,
                        Note = model.Note,
                        CoachId = int.Parse(model.CoachId),
                        StatusId = int.Parse(model.StatusId),
                        CreatedDate = DateTime.Now,
                        UserId=loginUserId,
                        CreatedBy = loginUserId,

                    };
                    // add record to database
                    _tourRepository.Add(tour);
                    TempData["SuccessMessage"] = "Tour Added Successfully";
                    return RedirectToAction("AddTour");
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    TempData["ErrorMessage"] = " Something went wrong.Please try again";
                    return RedirectToAction("AddTour");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = " Something went wrong.Please try again";
                return RedirectToAction("AddTour");
            }
        }
```

and my view

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1"  })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartDate, Model != null && Model.StartDate != null ? string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Model.StartDate) : "", new { @placeholder = "Enter Start Date", @class = "form-control date" } )
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EndDate, Model != null && Model.EndDate != null ? string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}", Model.EndDate) : "", new { @placeholder = "Enter End Date", @class = "form-control date", onblur = "compare();" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "errormsg"})
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Exceptions exist for a reason. They are thrown on the line item where they occur (attach the debugger to see this in action) and they (usually) have a descriptive message. In this case the error tells you exactly what is wrong, you can't assign a DateTime to a string. That should lead you to the conclusion that one of the sides of the assignment needs to be changed so change the target to a DateTime or change the value being assigned to a string. In this case the former would be the more correct solution.

Comment: I tried Everything, Taken field in DateTime or Convert.toDatetime..but nothing resolve this error..please review my code  once and what can i do to change it

Comment: `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]`  Try this  Data Annotation on your Model

Comment: @avi `DateTime` has no format, it's a binary value. Formats are used only when rendering datest into a string. `Convert.ToDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(model.StartDate).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"))` is meaningless as in the end, and with a lot of luck, it will produce the *original* `DateTime. If you want to display a `DateTime` property a certain way, specify the format in the  `DisplayFormat` attribute or in the HTML helpers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I even tried DisplayFormat..but nothing happened

Comment: PanagiotisKanavos is saying to change the type from `string` to `DateTime` in your *View Model class* for both `StartDate` and `EndDate` and *then also* apply the `DisplayFormatAttribute` to those properties.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the defined System.Globalization.Cultureinfo.Currentculture
You should ensure that the format is compatible with the text entered from the front-end.

Also be prepared to manage possible conversion error (all validations in javascript should be repeated in backend)

If you declare StartDate and EndDate as DateTime, you will not need to cast in the controller body

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
StartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(model.StartDate, "yyyy/M/d", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
EndDate = DateTime.ParseExact(model.EndDate, "yyyy/M/d", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]`

Also set your system date time format